# Android bitmap Recycled Error on Edittext focused

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have an Activity which displays 2 `ImageViews`, One is cropped to fit a square and the second one is based on the first on and is being `CenterCropped` to fill the screen as Background image With blur. The Background image blur process happens in a Thread.
Right after I'm stating that activity I'm trying to call another activity by `ActivityForResult` that has a simple dialog like view with `TextView` , Ok and Cancel buttons.
If I'm clicking on the Ok/Cancel buttons that activity finishes and everything is good, the problem happens when I'm trying to type in that `Edittext`, I get the error `Cannot draw recycled bitmap`, notice that I'm in another activity!! I thought that it might happened because the keyboard pushes the view up so I set the activity to SoftPan and still getting that message.
If I remove the part that makes the background blurry the app works fine.
Here is some of the Code:

This method Process the image in jni, Its about 3200px X 2400px (HAVE TO KEEP AT THE HIGHEST RES)

```
private void setImageViewResult()
{
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
    // store the bitmap in the JNI "world"
    final JniBitmapHolder bitmapHolder = new JniBitmapHolder(b);
    // no need for the bitmap on the java "world", since the operations are done on the JNI "world"
    b.recycle();
    // crop a center square from the bitmap, from (0.25,0.25) to (0.75,0.75) of the bitmap.
    // bitmapHolder.cropBitmap(width/4,height/4,width*3/4,height*3/4);
    // rotate the bitmap:
    bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
    // get the output java bitmap , and free the one on the JNI "world"
    b = bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();
    final int width = b.getWidth(), height = b.getHeight();
    // Bitmap b = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(f.getAbsolutePath(), BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()));
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;
    float boxSize = BOX_SIZE;// dpToPx(338);
    float boxCenterInScreenHeight = screenHeight / 2;
    float boxCenterInScreenWidth = screenWidth / 2;
    float boxYInScreen = boxCenterInScreenHeight - boxSize / 2;
    float boxXInScreen = boxCenterInScreenWidth - boxSize / 2;
    float boxHeightRatio = boxSize / screenHeight;
    float boxWidthRatio = boxSize / screenWidth;
    float yRatio = boxYInScreen / screenHeight;
    float xRatio = boxXInScreen / screenWidth;
    float CropFromY = b.getHeight() * yRatio;
    float CropFromX = b.getWidth() * xRatio;
    // float HeightAndWidthToCrop = b.getHeight() *
    // boxHeightRatio;
    float HeightAndWidthToCrop = b.getWidth() * boxWidthRatio;
    bitmapHolder.storeBitmap(b);
    b.recycle();
    bitmapHolder.cropBitmap((int) CropFromX, (int) CropFromY, (int) HeightAndWidthToCrop + (int) CropFromX, (int) HeightAndWidthToCrop + (int) CropFromY);
    bmp = bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();
    ivResult.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    setBackgroundBlur();
}
```

The Mothod for bluring the Background:

```
private void setBackgroundBlur()
{
    Config.getThreadPool().submit(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // bgFile = StorageUtils.newTempFile("jpg");
            try
            {
                // WebExecutor.executeSync(new DownloadImage(item.getImageCoverUrl(), bgFile));
                Bitmap bmp2 = ImageUtils.createCenterCrop(bmp, new DimensionsRect((int) (Config.getScreenDimens().getWidth() / 2f),
                                                                                  (int) (Config.getScreenDimens().getHeight() / 2f)));
                bmp2 = ImageUtils.setGpuImageFilter(bmp2, new GPUImageSaturationFilter(1));
                Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp2);
                c.drawColor(0x77000000);
                bmp2 = ImageUtils.setGpuImageFilter(bmp2, new GPUImageBoxBlurFilter(1f));
                System.gc();
                bgBitmap = bmp2;
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        android.util.Log.i("SEB BACKGROUND BLUR", "in method");
                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bgBitmap);
                        // ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bgBitmap);
                        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.toot)).setBackground(d);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(ivBackground).alpha(1).setDuration(500).start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The OnCreate Calls the SetImageViewResult and starts the second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rename_scan);
    setSoftPan();
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.popScan.name);
    final Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.popScan.ok);
    final Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.popScan.cancel);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {}
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to log from inside of the `setBackgroundBlur` method to check if it is being called for the second time after the Keyboard opens but it doesn't.

LogCat:

```
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:789)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:985)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13719)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12657)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13722)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12657)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12655)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12655)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13722)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12657)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12655)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13435)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13722)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2473)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12657)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12701)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-25 16:51:49.913: E/AndroidRuntime(29258):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 16:51:57.298: I/Process(29258): Sending signal. PID: 29258 SIG: 9
05-25 16:51:57.583: E/Trace(29333): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-25 16:51:57.678: D/dalvikvm(29333): GC_EXPLICIT freed 172K, 78% free 2416K/10660K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 24ms
05-25 16:51:57.773: E/BitmapFactory(29333): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.AppGate.mezuzot/cache/temp20140525_165145.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: from the looks of it it seems that you are trying to show a bitmap that has been recycled either programatically or by the system

Comment: plese post the logcat and show the portion of the code where the error is pointing

Comment: The background image is based on the first bitmap, the app works fine without setting the background to be blured so the "bmp" is not recycled, so what can cause that?                                                                                                                                                ADDED LOGCAT

Answer (score 0):

This is the portion of the code that is causing the exception:

```
 b.recycle();

// get the output java bitmap , and free the one on the JNI "world"
b = bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();
```

You cannot re-assign values to a recycled bitmap because the memory it was using is freed. You have to redecode it. Using any other variable in your case should work fine too.

Comment: As you can see the setBackgroundBlur being called after all of that Code, if I remove the call for setBackgroundBlur it works fine,I can start the ActivityForResult and do what ever I want. Lets say that the problem is really that code line, that makes 2 more problems, 1)I have to recycle that bitmap, Its a huge one to keep it in the memory 2) When exactly that code being called again? when the EditText has focus? if so than Why and how?

Comment: I understand but cant you recycle it at another position in the same function where it wont give you exception furthermore your variable naming is confusing and the crashing when edittext has focus doesnot make sense further more what does this method do setSoftPan();

Comment: SetsiftPan does exactly as the property in the xml menifist, only by code, and no I can't, as you can see I'm calling the method setBackgroundBlur right after I'm using that bitmap, and in that method I'm using that  bitmap object to create a new and scaled one. I know it doesn't make sence that because the focus but that's the problem, as I said earlier, I tried to do  somelogging in that method or any other method that related to those bitmaps to see if they are being called again, but they are not